# No such module 'SwiftDate'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

i'm new in iOS development. I've installed xcode i try to run some project that i need to reimplement for Android devices.

Error is like in the title:

> No such module 'SwiftDate'

I reinstalled xcode. Run

> 'pod update'

and

> 'pod install'

without any luck.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your project's folder, if the module is properly installed, you should see a file ending with `.xcworkspace`. Try opening your project by double-clicking on that file instead.

Comment: Magic. I tried this few times and it didn't work. Thank you.